# Find linked NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a bizarre issue.

I have written a package for Node for local use, and used NPM link to make it available for command line use globally.

Now I need to change the package, I can not find it on my drive but the package is still linked through NPM and usable.

Can NPM give me the path for linked modules?

Comment: It seems that `npm list` doesn't do that, but if you tell how the package and node was installed, and what platform you are using, we can find your missing package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NPM uses symlinks, you can always see them with `ls -l` command in the console.

See details in the [npm-link docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html).

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned above, The location of the Node.js files depends on the method you used to install it. I had the same issue and fixed it by locating the `node_modules` folder on my system and directly deleting the links.

If you downloaded and run, the installer package from the nodejs.org website, the Node.js main executables files `-- node and npm --` are located on the `/usr/local/bin` folder.

Note that I am on MacOS, not sure about Windows though.

Here's a link for more information and reference: [https://davescripts.com/location-of-nodejs-files-on-mac-os-x#:~:text=If%20you%20downloaded%20and%20run,usr%2Flocal%2Fbin%20folder](https://davescripts.com/location-of-nodejs-files-on-mac-os-x#:%7E:text=If%20you%20downloaded%20and%20run,usr%2Flocal%2Fbin%20folder).